# Custom token generation error in firebase admin sdk in node.js server and android client

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am using firebase admin-sdk in my node.js server to generate custom tokens.
Following is the code for it.

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin"),
express   = require("express"),
app       = express(),
bodyParser= require("body-parser"),
serviceAccount =  require("./skill-india-3e512-firebase-adminsdk-m4kyy-40528dd641.json"),
rot            =  require("rot");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true,}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

console.log(serviceAccount);
console.log(admin);
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://skill-india-3e512.firebaseio.com/"
});

app.get("/", function(req,res){
  console.log("Skill India Backend");
})


app.get("/id-tokens/:idToken/:registrationToken", function(req,res){
  // Receiving id-tokens
  var idToken = rot(req.params.idToken, -13);
  var registrationToken = rot(req.params.registrationToken, -13);

  console.log("idToken: " + idToken);
  console.log("registrationToken: " + registrationToken);

  admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken).then(function(decodedToken) {
      var uid = decodedToken.uid;
      console.log(uid);

      admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
        .then(function(customToken) {

          var payload = {
        $sceDelegate    data: {
              MyKey1: customToken
            }
          };

          var options = {
            priority: "high",
            tmeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
          };

          console.log("customToken: ", customToken);

          admin.messaging(),sendToDevice(registrationToken, payload, options)
            .then(function(response){
              console.log("Successfully Sent");
            })
            .catch(function(error){
              console.log("Error Encountered: " , error);
            });

        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
        });
    })

    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error receiving tokens");
    });

});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Server Started!");
})
```

I am receiving idToken and registrationToken via http, and after generating custom tokens I will be sending it back to client via FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging), but I am stuck in generating the uid.

Verification of id-tokens is not working. I am doing this on my localhost and using ngrok to make the url to make http requests.
This is my first time using firebase admin-sdk so any help would be appreciated.

I am receiving this error => Error receiving tokens.

Comment: Since you are receiving the idToken, can you manually try verifying the idToken to see if it's valid? You can use [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) to verify the idToken manually.

Comment: I am sorry the error has been resolved... The problem was with the asynchronousy.. the next function was being called without uid could be formed.... i have resolved it now

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it now..
The problem was with asynchronousy...
Next function was being called before the uid was formed.

Sorry for the trouble.
To solve the issue just put the next function inside the first so that uid can be formed first. :)